# Selenium works in Terminal but not the Python Shell

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running python on a Mac (10.15.6). When I run this script from the terminal, it works fine

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

But starting it from the Python IDLE or VSCode, I get the message:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

I have no clue why it works from the terminal and not from the shell. It would be great if someone could help me out or point me in a direction where I might find the answer :)

Comment: Run `python --version` in both places and see if it returns the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It's seems like the Python interpreter you're using in the shell is not the same one used by Vscode. You can [change the Python environment](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) to match the one you're using in your Shell, or even install `selenium` in the Python interpreter currently used with:

```
python -m pip install -U selenium
```

Answer (score 0):

Try typing `which python` in terminal and console, it will point out which python it is using. You can set the python again in VSCode using `⇧⌘P`, `Select interpreter` then choose the one that's working in terminal.